# Insert checked rows into database from html checkboxes and php from search results

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get code inserted from a search query generated table that is displayed on a webpage. The user can check a row in the table, and from there the apply button should submit the information to the mysql database.
I've looked for more information about this online for hours and cannot find any that fits this situation. I have tried using the checkbox array with a for each loop but it did not work. In the code the php there is for the search of the db done by the user. I need a way to get the checked rows into a database table.

```
<div class="SearchBar">

    <form action="volHome.php?go" method="POST" id="searchForm">

        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Search..">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Start Date</th>
                <th>End Date</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Organization</th>
            </tr>

            <?php
            try {
                $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=finalproject;port=3306;', 'root', '');
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'Not Connected: ', $e->getmessage();
                die('not connected');
            }

            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                if (isset($_GET['go'])) {
                    //  echo"<p>If statement being entered</p>";
                    $name = $_POST['name'];

                    $sql = "select o.City, Description, endDate, startDatee, org.Name from opportunity o join organizations org on o.O_ID = org.O_ID where o.city like '%$name%' or Description like '%$name%' or org.Name like '%$name%'";

                    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->execute();

                    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td><input type="checkbox" onclick="getRow(this)"/>', $row['Description'], '</td>';
                        echo '<td>', $row['startDatee'], '</td>';
                        echo '<td>', $row['endDate'], '</td>';
                        echo '<td>', $row['City'], '</td>';
                        echo '<td>', $row['Name'], '</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';

                    }

                }
            }

            ?>


        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't use prepared statements like that. It defeats there purpose, parameterize. What does `getRow` do?

Comment: i Forgot to get rid of the get row when I was attempting to use JavaScript with php to make this work.